# customtinywebdb, on deploying and going to the url, im getting 500 server error, pls suggest

Tags: google-app-engine

Im trying to develop an app using mit app inventor. I have downloaded sdk for  customtinywebdb. On deploying and going to the link, I am getting a 500 server error, please suggest possible reasons. During deployment all steps were successful

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking (and maybe the tour as well http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: The 500 error code indicates something happend server-side. And that's it. You must always check the app's logs to find out more details.

Comment: First test the development server locally..